# What happens in regression when each row has the same value in a given column?

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients

Suppose we have data like this:

```
3,5,1
3,6,1
2,4,1
4,5,1
3,6,1
2,4,1
1,4,1
```

Where the first column is `col1`, the second is `col2` and the third is `col3`.

Then after fitting `lm(col2 ~ col1 + col3)` in R, we get this output:

```
Coefficients:
(Intercept)         col1         col3  
      3.250        0.625           NA
```

`col3` has a coefficient of NA after fitting a linear model to this data. This makes me wonder if there is some mathematical reason why having a column where each row has the same value is a problem. Visualising this data in my mind, I can see that all the data would fit perfectly onto a plane, col2 = 1. I suspect it has something to do with this. Hence, what happens in regression when each row has the same value in a given column, in mathematical terms?

Comment: In mathematical terms, regression (with an intercept) always has a constant column.  Your output merely reflects that redundancy.  Check it out: display `model.matrix(col2 ~ col1 + col3)`.

Comment: Oh, so now the design matrix is not full rank! Thanks.

Comment: @Data now that you have found the answer, why don't you post it and accept it as an answer to your question? That will make it easier for later visitors to the site who might have the same question.